# Problems rendering one div on top of a p, p is still visible

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to appear on top of some UI elements below it.  Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="modal addmenu">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <div>
                <table><tr>
                    <td><div>Item 1</div></td>
                    <td><div>Item 2</div></td>
                </tr></table>
                </div>
            </p>

            <!-- This should be under the p above -->
            <p class="newmenu">
                <label for="new-menu">Name of a new menu:</label>
                <span>
                    <input id="new-menu">
                </span>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
.modal.addmenu fieldset div 
{
   z-index: 5000; /* Attempt to show div over p.newmenu */
   background-color: #ffffff; /* force white background? */
}

.modal.addmenu fieldset table { height: 70px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
.modal.addmenu fieldset table td { vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; line-height: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #404040; font-size: 15px; }
.modal.addmenu fieldset table td div { min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; height: 60px; border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px; padding: 15px; }
.modal.addmenu fieldset table td div.new { font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline; }

.modal.addmenu fieldset p.newmenu
{
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 0; /* attempt to show this under div above */
}
```

Basically, I want the first `<p>` tag to render on top of the second `<p>` tag.  I do not want to be able to see the *"Name of new menu"* and input area at all.  However, try as I might, these elements still bleed through.  I've confirmed on Chrome, Firefox and IE8.

In case you're wondering, the reason why I'm positioning the element using a negative top margin and not just hiding `p.newmenu` using `display` or `visibility` is I want to apply an animation that will "slide out" `p.newmenu` from underneath the div.  Thus, I need `p.newmenu` to be completely covered up by the div.

I've tried setting the `z-index` property on pretty much everything, I've tried different background colors, and I've messed around with every other style I can think of.  Does anyone know how to get the behavior I seek?  Thanks!

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/rm58T/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only elements with `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` position are affected by `z-index`.

Add `position:relative;` to `.modal.addmenu fieldset div` and `.modal.addmenu fieldset p.newmenu`.

[Fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rm58T/1/)